# SVG icon doesn't fit to the parent container

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to create social media links with SVG icons. I'm using `<svg>` and `<use>`.

I'm defining the SVG height and width but the icon doesn't fit.

Html:

```css
.footer__link{
  display: block;
  height: 7rem;
  width: 7rem;
  margin: 10px;
}

.footer__icon{
  fill: #3498db;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px #00000070;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="footer__link">
    <svg class="footer__icon">
      <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-facebook"></use>
    </svg>
</a>


sprite file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated by IcoMoon.io -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="752" height="32" viewBox="0 0 752 32">
<svg id="icon-facebook" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" x="0" y="0">
<path d="M19 6h5v-6h-5c-3.86 0-7 3.14-7 7v3h-4v6h4v16h6v-16h5l1-6h-6v-3c0-0.542 0.458-1 1-1z"></path>
</svg>
<svg id="icon-instagram" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" x="48" y="0">
<path d="M16 2.881c4.275 0 4.781 0.019 6.462 0.094 1.563 0.069 2.406 0.331 2.969 0.55 0.744 0.288 1.281 0.638 1.837 1.194 0.563 0.563 0.906 1.094 1.2 1.838 0.219 0.563 0.481 1.412 0.55 2.969 0.075 1.688 0.094 2.194 0.094 6.463s-0.019 4.781-0.094 6.463c-0.069 1.563-0.331 2.406-0.55 2.969-0.288 0.744-0.637 1.281-1.194 1.837-0.563 0.563-1.094 0.906-1.837 1.2-0.563 0.219-1.413 0.481-2.969 0.55-1.688 0.075-2.194 0.094-6.463 0.094s-4.781-0.019-6.463-0.094c-1.563-0.069-2.406-0.331-2.969-0.55-0.744-0.288-1.281-0.637-1.838-1.194-0.563-0.563-0.906-1.094-1.2-1.837-0.219-0.563-0.481-1.413-0.55-2.969-0.075-1.688-0.094-2.194-0.094-6.463s0.019-4.781 0.094-6.463c0.069-1.563 0.331-2.406 0.55-2.969 0.288-0.744 0.638-1.281 1.194-1.838 0.563-0.563 1.094-0.906 1.838-1.2 0.563-0.219 1.412-0.481 2.969-0.55 1.681-0.075 2.188-0.094 6.463-0.094zM16 0c-4.344 0-4.887 0.019-6.594 0.094-1.7 0.075-2.869 0.35-3.881 0.744-1.056 0.412-1.95 0.956-2.837 1.85-0.894 0.888-1.438 1.781-1.85 2.831-0.394 1.019-0.669 2.181-0.744 3.881-0.075 1.713-0.094 2.256-0.094 6.6s0.019 4.887 0.094 6.594c0.075 1.7 0.35 2.869 0.744 3.881 0.413 1.056 0.956 1.95 1.85 2.837 0.887 0.887 1.781 1.438 2.831 1.844 1.019 0.394 2.181 0.669 3.881 0.744 1.706 0.075 2.25 0.094 6.594 0.094s4.888-0.019 6.594-0.094c1.7-0.075 2.869-0.35 3.881-0.744 1.050-0.406 1.944-0.956 2.831-1.844s1.438-1.781 1.844-2.831c0.394-1.019 0.669-2.181 0.744-3.881 0.075-1.706 0.094-2.25 0.094-6.594s-0.019-4.887-0.094-6.594c-0.075-1.7-0.35-2.869-0.744-3.881-0.394-1.063-0.938-1.956-1.831-2.844-0.887-0.887-1.781-1.438-2.831-1.844-1.019-0.394-2.181-0.669-3.881-0.744-1.712-0.081-2.256-0.1-6.6-0.1v0z"></path>
<path d="M16 7.781c-4.537 0-8.219 3.681-8.219 8.219s3.681 8.219 8.219 8.219 8.219-3.681 8.219-8.219c0-4.537-3.681-8.219-8.219-8.219zM16 21.331c-2.944 0-5.331-2.387-5.331-5.331s2.387-5.331 5.331-5.331c2.944 0 5.331 2.387 5.331 5.331s-2.387 5.331-5.331 5.331z"></path>
<path d="M26.462 7.456c0 1.060-0.859 1.919-1.919 1.919s-1.919-0.859-1.919-1.919c0-1.060 0.859-1.919 1.919-1.919s1.919 0.859 1.919 1.919z"></path>
</svg>
<svg id="icon-twitter" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" x="96" y="0">
<path d="M32 7.075c-1.175 0.525-2.444 0.875-3.769 1.031 1.356-0.813 2.394-2.1 2.887-3.631-1.269 0.75-2.675 1.3-4.169 1.594-1.2-1.275-2.906-2.069-4.794-2.069-3.625 0-6.563 2.938-6.563 6.563 0 0.512 0.056 1.012 0.169 1.494-5.456-0.275-10.294-2.888-13.531-6.862-0.563 0.969-0.887 2.1-0.887 3.3 0 2.275 1.156 4.287 2.919 5.463-1.075-0.031-2.087-0.331-2.975-0.819 0 0.025 0 0.056 0 0.081 0 3.181 2.263 5.838 5.269 6.437-0.55 0.15-1.131 0.231-1.731 0.231-0.425 0-0.831-0.044-1.237-0.119 0.838 2.606 3.263 4.506 6.131 4.563-2.25 1.762-5.075 2.813-8.156 2.813-0.531 0-1.050-0.031-1.569-0.094 2.913 1.869 6.362 2.95 10.069 2.95 12.075 0 18.681-10.006 18.681-18.681 0-0.287-0.006-0.569-0.019-0.85 1.281-0.919 2.394-2.075 3.275-3.394z"></path>
</svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: you are mssing `.` before class names

Comment: Couldn't test it with your SVG, but with another one it works as expected

Comment: Please try: `<image xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-facebook"></image>` instead of the use element.  If this doesn't work, it would be nice to know how `img/sprite.svg` is looking.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answers. i will add the sprite file

Comment: I'm sorry your question was putted on hold. As I've commented before you need to use  `<image>` instead of use. Also you need to add some CSS to the sprite file SVG: `<style type="text/css">
 <![CDATA[ 
 svg > svg:not(:target) {
 display: none;
 }
  ]]> 
</style>`. Please check this pen: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/1f4c00cd7c83dcbd6a08e1fb29a3e394?editors=1100. For the sprite file take a look at this in view source: view-source:https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/socialSOF.svg